# Inserting Multiple Items based on IDs - Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have two tables `products` and `shipments` and the pivot table `product_shipment` with fields `product_id and shipment_no`. In the pivot table, there can be a shipment number eg. #4562 that contains 2 or more products. This is something i want to achieve.

Now this is how my codes works. When i select a product `hammer`, i am able to retrieve the id of `hammer`. When i select the id of another product `screwdrivers`, it replaces the id of `hammer` instead of storing both.

After inserting my data, i expect something of this sought in my **pivot table**

**Products Table**

```
 product_id   name
    1         hammer
    2         screwdriver
```

**Shipments Table**

```
shipment_no    courrier        
 4562          MaerskLine
```

**product_shipment - Pivot**

```
   shipment_no     product_no
     4562             1
     4562             2
```

This is where my i select my product checkbox

**HTML**

```
 <input onclick="return productSelected(this)" type="checkbox"
 id="{!! $product->id !!}" name="{!! $product->name !!}" />
```

How i select and retrieve my product id when i select a checkbox

**JS**

```
  function productSelected(product)
{

    $(".panel").append(
    '<input type="text"  value='+product.id+'   " id="product_id"  name="product_id" />'

}
```

How i save data into my database

**Controller**

```
$product_id = Input::get('product_id');
        $product_selected = Product::all()->where('id',$product_id)->first();

        $shipment_details = new Shipment(array(
            'shipment_no' => $request->get('shipment_no'),
            'courrier' => $request->get('courrier'),


        ));

        $product_id->shipments()->save($shipment_details);
```

**Shipment Model**

```
public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product')
        ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

**Product Model**

```
public function shipments()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Shipment')
        ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

**How can i get all the id's of the products i select and also have it look like what i have in my `pivot table`?**    Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you have relationships in the Models or not

Comment: @Maraboc Yes i do have relationship in the models. Its a many to many relationship

Comment: Can you add the code of the two Models ?

Comment: @Maraboc i have added the models. check  my update, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first change input names like this:

```
function productSelected(product)
{

    $(".panel").append(
    '<input type="text"  value='+product.id+'   " id="product'+product.id+'"  
     name="products[]" />'

}
```

You should get array products with all selected ids in your controller now. So you can do something like that:

```
$shipment_details = new Shipment(array(
        'shipment_no' => $request->get('shipment_no'),
        'courrier' => $request->get('courrier'),
));
$shipment_details->save();
$shipment_details->products()->sync($request->get('products'));
```

Of course you should have `manyToMany` relation with `Product` in your `Shipment` model.

Comment: oh that was so simple. Thank you very much